# can't see infopath form approved and enabled by central administration

Tags: infopath, central-administration, content-approval

following this processes:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/demo-deploy-an-administrator-approved-form-template-HA010205047.aspx

I am trying to upload a form containing some C# code created in infopath 2010 into my sharepoint 2010 site as a site collection admin.  In order to do so, I have to submit the form first to be approved and enabled by a site collection administrator.  When I upload it in central administration and enable it in the list of infopath form templates, I thought I was supposed to see it on the site form library, but I do not see it there and therefore cannot enable it as a site feature.  What step by step processes do I need to take to get this working?

I have tried to enable some features first of all but ran into the problem of not being able to see the site collection features even though I 
am a site collection admin. (this solution below is not working for me because I still cannot see it, only site features).  Has anyone ever encountered this? I have the same problem as Michael in the comments section of the below solution.  I am sure I am a site collection admin but I still can't see site collection features in central administration.

http://moustafa-arafa.blogspot.hk/2010/05/cant-see-site-collection-features-in.html

> If you are trying to find out "site collection features" link in the
>   site setting page in sharepoint 2010 and you couldn't find out the
>   site administration section at all this is because the logged in user
>   doesn't have a permission as a site collection administrator, open
>   central administration site:
>
> 1) Select application management tab. 2) Click on change site
>   collection administrators link under site collection tab. 3) add your
>   self as site collection administrator. 4) refresh the site settings
>   page and you will see all site collection administration section.
>
> Michael said...  Hey thanks for the reply, I went back and made sure I
>   was the admin of the site collection before checking site settings.
>   But I don't see a "site collection features" option there either.
>
> May 17, 2010 3:07 PM

Update 1.  Trying Gennady's suggested soltuion, but still encountering the same problem:

1. under Central Administration/Site Actions/Site Settings, I see the following clickable choices:

[image: Clickable Choices]

--  I confirm I am both a site collection admin and a member of the farm administrators group....  I can upload the file onto Central Administration but am not able to send it to the Site so far...

Answer (score 1):

> I have the same problem as Michael in the comments section of the
>   below solution

IMO (because I am on Sharepoint online without access to Central Administration and not 100% sure what are the differences with on-premise Sharepoint Server setup) "**Site Collection Features**" are under "**Site Collection Administration**" upon navigating  **Site Actions** > **Site Settings**

Though, IMO, it is not used for template form administration approval.

> In order to do so, I have to submit the form first to be approved and
>   enabled by a **site collection administrator**

Server **farm administrators** verify and upload form templates, after which site administrators can activate and manage form templates on the site collections that they own. Check for more details [Manage administrator-approved form templates (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921.aspx)

Update:
Sorry, I cannot help b/c I use Sharepoint Online (Office 365) where there is no Central administration as well as no administration approval (it is done once for all templates and forever, IMO).

Though I just wanted to mention about discrepancy in that online docs tell about farm administrator, the publishing wizard insists on Sharepoint server administrator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  Let me update my post with more information related to your answer.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, this is completely different in Sharepoint Online which I use. Can't help.